# The constructor Service(URL, QName, WebServiceFeature[]) is undefined

Tags: java, web-service, jax-ws

Estou consumindo um WebService em minha aplicação Java e estou encontrando o seguinte erro:

> The constructor Service(URL, QName, WebServiceFeature[]) is undefined

```
public AnaliseCredito(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE, features);
}
```

O problema é que estou utilizando o `JAX-WS 2.2` que, segundo a [documentação](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jaxws-api/2.2/javax/xml/ws/Service.html), possui o construtor em questão.

Inclusão da dependência no meu `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: sua classe estende a classe  javax.xml.ws.Service?

Comment: Sim, @adelmo00.

Comment: Já tive exatamente o mesmo problema. Qual a versão da JDK que vc esta utilizando?

Comment: JDK8, @AlexandreStrevenski.

Comment: Verifica no java build path se o projeto esta utilizando a JDK 8, pois eu tive este problema, quando estava utilizando a JDK 1.6_15 e troquei para 1.7, gerei novamente os stubs e funcionou, depois pesquisei na internet e descobri que a causa do problema é a versão do JAX-WS, estava utilizando 2.0 porém os stubs precisavam de classes que existem na 2.1 (que não estava implementada no JDK que eu utilizava).

Comment: Detectei que o projeto está usando a `jaxws-api 2.1` que tem incluída na `jaxws-rt 2.2.10`, vou testar fazer um `<exclude>`.

Comment: @EduardoSilva avisa se deu certo, mas acredito que seja versão do JDK.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30818/discussion-between-alexandre-strevenski-and-eduardo-silva).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era que estou utilizando [Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/),  que registra a si mesmo como o provider JAX-WS na JVM, dessa forma mesmo que eu tenha o `jaxws-rt : 2.2` em meu classpath/pom ele não será utilizado, a correção foi criar o arquivo

```
/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
```

com o seguinte conteúdo

```
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl
```

Veja também: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/ws/spi/Provider.html#provider()